# prevent socket io to disconnet when clicking on tel:, mailto, skype links

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I just noticed that socket io is disconnecting when I click on a link `<a></a>` that has href= to tel: or mailto: or skype.
I'm asking if there is a short/simple workaround this issue.
If link target is set to "_blank" then socket io stays connected but I don't find this a preferred solution!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture and suppress the event before it propegates to the window.

Google: js event bubbling.

Now, as to how to capture and suppress the event:

First, you will want to id the element producing the event or its container.

Next, set up a document load event handler.

Within the document load event handler, attach a click event handler to the previously ided element.

The click handler should have one parameter, "event" and return void.

Now, google: Javascript event type, and learn about the different methods you can call on the event.

I believe the one you need to call is event.stopPropagation (), but the documentation (I suggest MDN) should provide an authoritative reference.

Next, in the event handler, implement custom handling code (opening a new tab, setting location of current tab, etc.).

Comment: Sorry but I don't find your solution a good one even if you struggled to explain in details. I believe the main idee/ tehnic behind this is to run those kind of links in an iframe (using js; e.preventDefault() and pass that link into the iframe and then execute .click() ). Your answer is like a circle and it won't work. Open new tab, setting location ...  .To open a new tab I should simply set the link target to _blank and it is solved. Any way thanks.